# Displaying Results from database, based on two dropdown menus

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, dropdown

Before I address the issue, to the moderators: if by any chance the title is not accurate, please feel free, to make any necessary chances.

To the matter at hand:

I have created a database (currently running on localhost) that looks as follows:

---

### Id| Country | PlayerName | FootballTeam| NationalTeam

What I am trying to accomplish is the following:
To create two dropdown-menus (one for country, and one for PlayerName) that will allow the user/visitor to make one of the following choices:

1. Choose a country
2. Choose a PlayerName
3. Or, choose “Country” AND “PlayerName”

and once clicking the Submit button to filter the results from the database accordingly.

Based on the above 3 choices the results of the database should be displayed in something like a table format (I think - > I am open to any suggestions regarding a display format).

Bottom line is that the format should look like this:

Country 1 | PlayerName1 | FootballTeam 1| NationalTeam1 (line break)

Country 2 | PlayerName2 | FootballTeam 2| NationalTeam2 (line break)
…

---

How am I to go about it? 
Can this be done and if yes, how can I do it?

I kindly thank you in advance for your suggestions and advice.

Comment: "*Can this be done..*" => **Yes**  "*..how can I do it?*" => **Try**. Show your tried code. If any issues come. Feel free to ask.

Comment: Hi Nana. I will take it that you are not arrogant towards me but rather that you are trying to be helpful; so I will go for the second option. As said, if you would have read I am asking for advice, like pointing to the right direction or links etc. so as to work on the code etc. If I would know how to do it, then rest reassured I would ask the question. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into "cascading dropdownlists" for your drop down menu's. there are some libraries out there that feature this. (I've used kendo UI before to implement this)

If you managed that than you have fixed the hard part. You can easily generate a table to display the information from your database. You could request this info using an ajax request to generate the content dynamically or you use a submit instead.

I hope this is enough of a guideline for you!

Comment: Thanks for your replay Jester. I will look into it and once I have done my research in this department I will get back to you to let you know how it went (hope that its alright and I am not bothering you). Once again I thank you for your guidance

Comment: i don't mind at all. feel free to reply at all times :)